# Can't plot step response in Octave

Tags: plot, octave

Iam trying to plot step response in Octave (v 4.0.3) using this code:

```
pkg load control
clf;
s = tf('s');
g = 1/(2*s^2+3*s+4);
step(g);
```

But I get always the same error:

```
error: matrix cannot be indexed with .
error: called from
    plot at line 198 column 7
    __time_response__ at line 207 column 13
    step at line 74 column 10
```

If I used the same code in another computer with Octave 5.0.2 the code works perfectly, so I guess this is some kind of problem with this version.
I just want to know if there is some kind of workaround to plot my step response, cause this I need this particular version of Octave, so upgrade it is not a solution for my right now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`plot` has likely changed quite a bit since that old version of Octave came out, and you didn't mention the package version, but I'm guessing you are probably trying to use a current version of control?  The newest version would have been coded to accommodate any changes in Octave since then.  Best bet might be to try to uninstall the control package (`pkg uninstall control`) and find an old version from around the same time as Octave 4.0.3.

According to the [Octave Major Release History](https://wiki.octave.org/Release_History) page, 4.0.3 came out on 2016-07-01.  Looking at the [Control Package News](https://octave.sourceforge.io/control/NEWS.html) page, you probably want to try control-3.0.0, Release Date: 2015-10-30.  (the next version was in 2018 right around Octave 4.2.2, and might also work. I didn't see a note about the plot or step function behavior changing, so you might have to try a couple versions to find one that works with plot from 4.0.3.)

The [Octave Control Package page](https://octave.sourceforge.io/control/index.html) has a link to [Older Versions](https://octave.sourceforge.io/released-packages/) which just takes you to the SourceForge file host. Navigating from there to [Octave Forge Packages](https://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20Forge%20Packages/), [individual package releases](https://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20Forge%20Packages/Individual%20Package%20Releases/), will give you a chronological package download list where you can find different control packages to try. Scroll down or do a Find for 'control' and you should see 3.0.0 there.

Comment: Thanks Nick! Iam gonna give it a try on this. Iam using Octave on Debian 9, and i guess this is the default version for this distro. You are right. Iam using control version 3.2.0. So Iam gona try to downgrade it. Iam using old Octave versions because I have found (Iam just starting to learn) that this versions works better with Peter Corke Robotics libraries.